# go tool: no such tool "tour"

Tags: macos, go

I'm trying out Go for the first time. I was following [these docs](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/3) and wanted to run the go tour locally, but I haven't figured out how to get it to work.

Where is the tool "tour" supposed to be found?
I'm on OSX 10.11.3, and I installed Go via Homebrew
my Go entries in `.zshrc`

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/code/Go
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Comment: What was the reason for a down vote? Upvoting to counter that unhelpful negativity.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`tour` is not installed by default with an installation of go. You need to `go get` it:

```
go get golang.org/x/tour/gotour
```

Docs: https://github.com/golang/tour/

Comment: After installing that, I found `gotour` inside my $GOPATH/bin, and I could run it manually e.g. `./gotour`. But `go tool tour` still doesn't work for some reason. Something wrong with my path maybe?

Comment: Nevermind, I can see that the package was supposed to be run like that, according to the README.

Answer (score 11):

I had a problem too. This's my solution, on OSX let try

```
gotour
```

With version `go1.8.1 darwin/amd64`

Comment: You are required to run `go get golang.org/x/tour/gotour` to install `gotour` binary into your local `$GOPATH/bin` path. Then `gotour` should work because it plays as a bin executable, which is directly accessible by your terminal.

Answer (score 6):

It works for me using go1.4, but not with go1.7. If you just run `go tool`, it gives you a list of known tools. They seem to have removed it from tools.

```
$ gvm use go1.7
$ go tool
addr2line
api
asm
cgo
compile
cover
dist
doc
fix
link
nm
objdump
pack
pprof
trace
vet
yacc

$ gym use go1.4
$ go tool
6a
6c
6g
6l
addr2line
cgo
cover
dist
fix
nm
objdump
pack
pprof
tour      # <--- here
vet
yacc
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it is no longer `gotour`. And secondly, for the time being, the tour package is located at: `golang.org/x/website/tour` as opposed to what [A Tour of Go Welcome Page](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/3) says.

So, at least for now:

### The correct way to `get` tour is:

```
go get golang.org/x/website/tour
```

Or,

```
go install golang.org/x/website/tour@latest
```

After which you can run the command in the terminal:

```
$ tour
2021/06/22 17:46:48 Serving content from /home/user/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/website/tour@v0.0.0-20210616181959-e0d934b43647
2021/06/22 17:46:48 A browser window should open. If not, please visit http://127.0.0.1:3999
2021/06/22 17:46:52 accepting connection from: 127.0.0.1:33192
```

---

To find out where it has been installed, you can do `which tour`:

```
$ which tour
/home/user/go/bin//tour
```

---

[reference](https://github.com/golang/tour/issues/1203#issuecomment-854532853)

Comment: In 2021 this is the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Because of changes in Go package management and introduction of modules, this has changed since the original question. Thus, for future reference (as this is the first Google result), if you have not configured GOPATH environment variable

```
go get golang.org/x/tour
$HOME/go/bin/tour
```

Note that the executable is called "tour" instead of "gotour".

Source (with full explanation of why and details): https://stephencharlesweiss.com/getting-going-with-golang/

Answer (score 2):

I've got:

> golang.org/x/tour/gotour has moved to golang.org/x/tour

So, this works for me:

```
go get golang.org/x/tour
```

then:

```
tour
```

Comment: Thanks! Also for me with go1.13.4.windows this is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

When you install go, `tour` is not installed by default. You need to do a `go get golang.org/x/tour/gotour`. This downloads `gotour` in your workspace.

If you configured your PATH properly, `gotour` command from anywhere in the terminal will open up your browser, but if PATH is not configured properly, do a

```
   $GOPATH/bin/gotour
```

This command can be used from anywhere in your command line and it opens tour in your default browser

http://whipperstacker.com/2015/09/27/how-to-run-the-go-tour-locally/

https://github.com/golang/tour/blob/master/README.md

Comment: If your GOPATH is unset, but default you may want to do `${GOPATH:-$HOME/go}/bin/gotour` as it will work in either case.

Answer (score -1):

Once `gotour` is installed, it’s executable like other executables are typically stored in the `bin` directory of your workspace. Inside the `bin` directory `./gotour` will invoke or start `gotour`, elsewhere the `gotour` will need to be preceded by a path to where the executable is located. In other words `$GOPATH/bin/gotour` will invoke or start `gotour` when you are not inside the `bin` directory.